# Should the shaliah tzibur and congregation face the direction the Aron points if it isn't pointing toward Jerusalem?

Tags: synagogue, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, shulchan-aruch, tefillah-betzibbur

If the rear of the Aron points in any direction other than toward Jerusalem, which way should the shaliah tzibur and congregation face

-when praying the Amidah?

-during the rest of tefillah?

Do the ramah and mehaber and/or sefaradi/ashkeazi poskim differ on this?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-precisely-oriented-towards-jerusalem-should-we-face-for-praying/4030#4030

Comment: @SethJ Gershon's link does not take the aron kodesh factor into account. Meaning user5329 is asking if the aron kodesh trumps the requirement to face Jerusalem

Answer (score 3):

According to Mishna Brurah 94:9, Halacha Brurah 94:2 even if the aron is facing in a different direction, one should pray facing Jerusalem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Machlokes, summarized somewhat [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=84). First, it depends on what the rest of the congregation is doing. If they will all Daven facing Yerushalim, this is preferable. But if they aren't, it is probably not appropriate to do something different.