# Which way to face when davening at the Kotel

Tags: halacha, tefilla, beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem, kotel-western-wall

It seems that at the Kotel, the general practice is to daven directly facing the wall. (Speaking from experience.)

However, i thought we were supposed to face the *kodesh hakodashim*, which has a "handy" dome as a landmark. From the Kotel plaza, that's actually to the left of the Wall.

Should one follow the general custom and face the Wall, or face the site of the *kodesh hakodashim*?

(Side note: Could people be facing the Wall because of a misconception that it's the top holy site?)

Comment: When I was at the Kotel for a Vesikin minyan, all of them faced the kotel, except one. They looked the Yeshivish/Litvish types. They were turned slightly to the left.

Comment: How is this different from any other shul where everyone faces the wrong direction?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because here i have a genuine question which way is proper.

Comment: You think there might be a reason to face a pile of stones?

Comment: @DoubleAA In the popular mind, it's not just "a pile of stones". If the proper thing to do is face Har Habayit, why don't you just answer so?

Comment: You should probably change both "har habayit" and "kodesh hakodashim" in your question to "bet hamikdash". See _SA OC_ 94:1.

Comment: The idea of not having access to Har Habayit to pray is something that would not have been considered until recently. In past years, we either had access to Har Habayit, or no access to that part of Jerusalem at all. There like therefore is not much written about this question until recently.

Comment: @Scimonster which way does the Aron face in the synagogue right off the kotel plaza ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second rosh yeshiva in my yeshiva, R' Dovid Stefansky, told me he had asked this question to his rosh yeshiva, Rav Shach, while pointing out that the correct direction would seem to be diagonally left.

Rav Shach answered sarcastically: Go ahead and face that way, if it pleases you so much to be different from everyone else!

Recognizing the Western Wall Plaza as a synagogue where people pray in the wrong direction, some hold that you should turn only your face towards *Kodesh Hakodoshim* (*Mishnah Berurah* 94:10), because an individual is prohibited from praying in a different direction than the rest of the congregation (*Aruch Hashulchan* 94,13). However, other hold that you may pray to the east at your discretion (*Machatzis Hashekel* 94,3).

Comment: Right, because his pleasure wouldn't come from following Halacha...

Comment: @DoubleAA Now, what to do in a synagogue with aron hakodesh in wrong direction end would be a very relevant question. E.g. [South Fallsburg](https://goo.gl/maps/LxflP) facing south-west (should be East or North-East).

Comment: @NBZ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37590/should-the-shaliah-tzibur-and-congregation-face-the-direction-the-aron-points-if

Comment: And, we might say that the Aron at the Kotel is facing the wrong way. They (there are multiple aronot) face the Wall, not the Kodesh Hakadashim.

Answer (score 1):

My Rebbe the Cheif Rabbi of the old city Rav Avigdor Nevenzahl Shlit"a told me that it is a bizayon to the kosel to daven towards the left.

Another reason why one would not need to face left is because it is an inherent safek as to where the actual makom hamikdash is located. Although one could be somech on the Ridvaz who says that the makom hamikdash is "tachas kipas hasela". However Rav Moshe Shternbuch Shlit"a in Teshuvos v' Hanhagos; basing himself upon other sources, doubts the assumption of the Ridvaz(which is actually based upon what others said).This is also the reason why going onto Har Habayis is considered an Issur Chamur which has been proclaimed assur by all great rabbonim of the previous generation.

Comment: What's wrong with a bizayon to the kosel? And shouldn't that at least be better than a bizayon to the mikdash?

Comment: Do you mean a Safek Issur Chamur?

Comment: "proclaimed assur by all great rabbonim of the previous generation" It's hard for me to think of a case where someone said that phrase without exaggerating.

Comment: Yes i agree it is a safek issur chamur

Comment: However, my statement in regards to the Kol Koreh is not an exaggeration, look at the Kol Koreh issued years ago. It runs the gamut from the Chief Rabbis of the state of Israel to the heads of the even the most Chareidi institutions. This view was at one point universally shared, although some may have felt that view for differing reasons (ie. Halachic, political etc.)

Comment: "What's wrong with a bizayon to the kosel? And shouldn't that at least be better than a bizayon to the mikdash?" obviously bizayon mikdash is more chamur, but in light of my second point it is more easily understood (and although i brought it as a second answer i believe this is what underlies my Rebbes point of view) being that it is only a safek makom hamikdash, it is only a safek bizayon mikdash, however turning left is a vadai bizayon to the kosel, memeilah its better tobe makpid on the vaidai bizayon, rather than the safek kiyum of davening towards the mosque. hope this answers

Comment: It's not clear you should apply Ein Safek Motzi Midei Vadai; for instance, we would probably violate a minhag to avoid a safek deoraytal. Also, you still haven't explained what's wrong with a bizayon to the kotel. It's just a pile of stones...

Comment: You give the impression that everyone forbade it due to it's being a (safek) issur chamur. Those who forbade it for political reasons may not maintain their prohibition in a different political climate. Moreover, demonstrating that the old Kol Korehs had a _range_ of opinions doesn't demonstrate that it was unanimous.

Comment: Finally, everyone agrees that the Safek area is not directly behind the Kotel Plaza. All the arguments are clear that the area adjacent to the Plaza is a later addition to the mountain.

Comment: first i take issue with you calling the kosel a "pile of stones" and second look at R Moshe Shternbuch teshuva where he actually proposes thats the makom hamikdash is almost directly behind the kosel.
secondly, the issue of issur krisus of bias mikdash was and is a consideration at the very least, even according to the opinions thats were based off political realities

Comment: thirdly, the fact that there was a wide range of opinons absolutely shows that the act of going up on har habayis is unanimously frowned upon, for whatever reason. again i reiterate, the issue of safek bias mikdash was and always is a consideration in this issue. not taking it into account is absurdity of the highest level.

Comment: What exactly are you taking issue with? A random wall near Har Habayit isn't all that unique. "a range ....shows...unanimously..." what? Did you just say that in a sentence? I'm not ignoring the issur. I'm just informing you that it's not like the entire mountain is a safek. We know some stuff. We actually know a great deal more than anyone else in the last 500 years or so, at least.

Comment: Ok I read the "responsum" (if you can call it that). He barely looks at any archaeological evidence at all and bases himself mostly on one rumor about how the Muslim's chose where to build the Dome of the Rock. He's just trying to justify the tradition of those who face straight (throwing out the traditional identification of the Makom Mikdash in the process), as if that location was the one Jews davened at since the Churban. He should really just stick to Halacha, instead of trying to be a trained historian and archaeologist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14872/discussion-between-nafkamina-and-double-aa).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be completely unfounded:

[Talmud Yerushalmi Masechet Brachot daf 35.](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14139&st=&pg=70)

There, it says that anyone praying inside Jerusalem should face Har HaBayit. Seeing as how being in front of the Kotel is below Har HaBayit, it could be interpreted to mean that one should face Har HaBayit itself, and not adjust so that you face the Kodesh HaKadashim.

While it is more logical to interpret this in terms of approximations, the basic reading would imply facing directly at the wall.

Comment: Except behind the kotel isn't har habayit. It's a later extension with no holiness. Har Habayit itself also only starts somewhat to the left of the Kotel Plaza.