# Praying while Facing Away from Kotel?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, kotel-western-wall

I was recently at the Kotel during Erev Shabbat, and I saw that while most people were facing toward the wall, a few were facing away from it, toward the entrance ramp, and fervently praying in that direction. They were not standing alone, but amongst a minyan in which most other people were facing toward the wall. (And no, it wasn't just at the end of Lecha Dodi, it was for most of Maariv.) I know that outward appearance is not a good way to tell, but they looked like religious Jews to me. Why were they doing this?

Comment: Facing to the right or the left? See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38826/which-way-to-face-when-davening-at-the-kotel?rq=1

Comment: Why would anyone face the kotel when praying? It's just a wall

Comment: @Scimonster I saw that question before posting. These people were not facing right or left, but backwards.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am not sure what your point is. As you could surely understand, facing the Kotel is a lot closer to facing the Kodesh Hakodashim than facing away from the wall.

Comment: Maybe they were facing Meah Shearim - their Kodesh Kodoshim. ;-)